# Obtener dimensiones con javascript de una imagen establecida desde javascript en un div?

Tags: javascript

Quiero establecer la imagen que se muestra en un div mediante javascript. Hasta ahí todo bien. Pero necesito obtener las dimensiones de la misma. Con este código me da 0x0 la primera vez pero al recargar la página me da las dimensiones correctas. Alguna idea de como conseguir que lo haga a la primera ??? Gracias.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>probando</title>
</head>
 
<body>
 <div id="ventanainformacion"></div>  

   
<script>

var elemento=document.getElementById("ventanainformacion");
elemento.innerHTML="";
 var info = '<img class="mini" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-Kc7NMxQFQhY%2FVanepvrVIvI%2FAAAAAAAAAzs%2FqqxyWLdF-rU%2Fs1600%2FGaren-Rainbow-modgamelol.com.png&f=1">';
elemento.innerHTML=info;
var foto;
foto=document.querySelector(".mini");
var ancho=foto.naturalWidth;
var alto=foto.naturalHeight;

alert(ancho+'x'+alto);
 
 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Estas probandolo en firefox?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, Edge... En todos pasa lo mismo. Me da que cuando recargas la página funciona porque ya la tenga en caché, pero no sé... Gracias.

Comment: Creo que la respuesta a esta pregunta puede servirte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/246353/c%C3%B3mo-solucionar-este-bug-de-firefox-al-usar-offsetwidth-width-de-java-script/

Comment: Lo probaré a ver que tal. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Gracias Francisco, hice var foto1=new Image(); luego establecí su src y con foto1.onload=function () { ...... }  como sugeriste me va de lujo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que comprobar si la imagen esta cargada. Si la imagen esta cargada puedes utilizar los valores de la anchura y la altura de la imagen.

Por favor lea los comentarios en el código.

```js
var elemento=document.getElementById("ventanainformacion");

// crea una nueva imagen
var info = new Image();
// establece el valor del atributo src de la nueva imagen
info.src = "https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-Kc7NMxQFQhY%2FVanepvrVIvI%2FAAAAAAAAAzs%2FqqxyWLdF-rU%2Fs1600%2FGaren-Rainbow-modgamelol.com.png&f=1"

// cuando la imagen esté cargada
info.onload = function(){
// agrega la imagen al elemento
  elemento.appendChild(info);
  // recupera el valor de la anchura y la altura de la imagen cargada
  var ancho = info.width;
  var alto  = info.height;
  
  a.innerHTML = ancho;
  b.innerHTML = alto;
}
```

```html
<p>ancho: <span id="a"></span>px</p>
<p>alto: <span id="b"></span>px</p>
<div id="ventanainformacion"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias !!! :-)